# Error bars in feature selection increase when using more features?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, training-data, feature-selection

I am following [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-forest-importances-py) to determine feature importance using Random Forests. When using numerous features and only a subset of these features, these are the results I observe, respectively:

[image: All features]

[image: Subset of features]

Is there a particular reason the error bars increase drastically when using all possible features? Is there any significance to a negative quantity? (Note: the particular labels on the x-axis in the two plots do not necessarily correspond.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using only the most important features then there is less chance of an error happening (or less chance of the model incorrectly learn a pattern where it shouldn't).

**Without using feature importances**

- There is a high chance that your model is captruing patterns where it shouldn't and hence giving importance to lesser important feature where it shouldn't.
- Also, Random Forest is an ensemble of decision trees, some might capture the correct feature importances, some might not.
- The most importance ones have such a high error rate because in some trees, they may be absolutely ignored altogther or given least importance. While some might capture it correctly
- Hence, you have both ends of the spectrum resulting in such a high error rate.

**Using feature importances**

- You eliminate the least important features successively resulting in the fact that in successive trees, that feature will not be considered at all ( Hence lesser chance of any error happening in feature importance)
- Doing this successively improves the chances of more imporatant features to be selected again and again for splitting, hence the error margin is comparatively less